# ! LaTeX Error: File 'natbib.sty' not found

Tags: bibtex, errors, compiling, natbib

I have a problem compiling an article using `natbib`. I am using WinEdt to compile, for example this what I found online:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibtest.bib}
@book{goossens93,
        author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
        title = "The Latex Companion",
        year = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{goossens93}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibtest}

\end{document}
```

I do:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  (`latex`)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  (`latex`)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>  (`bibtex`)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  (`latex`)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  (`latex`)

and finally

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  (`dvips`), `pspdf`

And in the `pdf` I don't get the name of the cited authors but I get instead: `(?)`

Also I get an error when I do  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>:

> "! LaTeX Error: File 'natbib.sty' not found"

I do not know how to fix that because `natbib.sty` is in the folder: *\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib

I will very much appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you try refreshing MiKTeX's database?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem